# Template member function failed to call in case if class object is composed-off in other class

Tags: c++, templates

Template member functions allow us to parameterise functions independently for a class they belong to. They are supported for both template and non-template classes and it worked fine if we directly call it from class object.
But in case if class is composed-off in other class c++ compiler fail to resolve it. In my case I am able to call template member function directly from object but it fails( MsgParser::run(){source.showType();}) when object is composition. logic behind it ?

```
struct A{};    
struct B{};    
class DataSource{
    public:
        template<class Type>    
        void showType(){
        std::cout<<std::endl<<typeid(Type).name();    
    }
    void disp(){ std::cout<<std::endl<<"All OK";}    
    private:    
};      
    
template<class Source>    
class MsgParser{    
public:    
    MsgParser(Source &s):source(s){}    
    void run(){    
        source.disp();    
        source.showType<A>(); // failed to call ??     
    }       
private:    
    Source &source;    
};      
    
int main()    
{    
    DataSource dataSource;    
    dataSource.showType<A>();
    MsgParser<DataSource> msgParser(dataSource); 
    msgParser.run();    
    return 1;    
}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Add `.template` to the call: `source. template showType<A>()`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
 source.showType < A > (b);
```

is ambigious to the compiler not knowing yet what kind of template argument you will pass to it. It might as well be a class member `showType` inside `source` that is compared to `A` and `b`. Therefore you will have to **add `.template` to the call** of `showType` to **distinguish it from a comparison**

```
 source. template showType<A>();
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/a5Xow01dLiNzq3Fb)

If you are interested in when to add `typename` and `template` refer to [this lengthy explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/9938686).

Comment: @AdityaKumar I linked a detailed explanation. It is basically there to distinguish it from a simple comparison. Wait a second, I will add a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @AdityaKumar I suggest you to understand first why you need to use `typename` for a depedent name, the reason why you need to put `. template` is basically the same